# Puppet Master not pulling changes to agents

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

I have added following code in site.pp

```
node default {
file {'/etc/motd':
ensure => present,
content => "Motd Updated.\n",
}
}
```

But when running following command in one agent it is not updating all agents or nodes.

```
puppet agent -t
```

Can some one assist what I am missing ?

Comment: What do the logs on the client and the server say ?

Comment: it is not reporting anything related to it

Comment: any help please >

Comment: Are your nodes defined specifically in the site.pp or are you only using node default? IIRC you cannot use both for a single node.

Comment: @Frederik only using node default

Comment: Just to confirm - you will need to run `puppet agent -t` on _each_ node in order for all nodes to see the change. Puppet is a master/slave model where slaves will pull config from the master - not the other way around.